# How to open mat-menu from button click of a dynamically created open layers custom control?

Tags: angular, angular-material, openlayers

I create open layer custom controls / buttons to open-layers map like this in app.component that has open-layers map.

```
  private createMenuOpener(): HTMLElement {
    const element = document.createElement('div');
    element.className = `ol-control button menu-opener`;
    
    // for other buttons the click handler is set
    // but mat-menu is opened with [matMenuTriggerFor] 
    element.addEventListener('click', () => {
       
       // if this is set, it needs to open mat-menu

    });
    return element;
  }
```

HTML for app.component just contains the 3rd party map component :

```
<app-map-openlayers></app-map-openlayers>
```

The mat-menu could be defined in a separate component or in app.component's template.

Possible solutions:

1. Open mat-menu without using matMenuTriggerFor.
2. Set matMenuTriggerFor for the native element created with document.createElement.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** (based on clarification in comments)

You need to pass a reference to `MatMenuTrigger` to the constructor of the custom OpenLayers control, and then call `openMenu()` on it in the click handler.

This can be difficult if you don't have access to the map creation code (`new Map...`), but if you do have access to it, then it's relatively straightforward.

I've prepared a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-39cnhy?file=src/app/rotate-north-control.ts) that demonstrates this. It's a modified copy of the custom control example you linked, but this time it also opens an Angular material menu.

**Previous Answer**

In general, in Angular you don't create elements in your component templates by using `document`.

Instead, have a variable which indicates whether the button exists, and use an `ngIf` in your template to include it:

```js
private createMenuOpener(): void {
   this.showButton = true;
}
```

```html
<button *ngIf="showButton" 
        class="ol-control button menu-opener" 
        [matMenuTriggerFor]="...">
  Open
</button>
```

Comment: Have you tried this with open layers map?

Comment: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/custom-controls.html

Comment: Please try. I tried and didn't succeed. That's why I'm following the open-layers examples how it's done.

Comment: Try what exactly? this is too general, maybe refine your question?

Comment: I think I see what you mean, you want an openlayers custom control, that also has an angular function?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I need (and IMHO also asked).

Comment: Forgive me for not understanding immediately what you were asking :) - please show your code that creates the map `const map = new Map...` including template and a little bit of context

Comment: No problem! Thanks for trying to help me out. Anyway this is existing large production app that uses 3rd party wrapper control for the actual open-layers map control.  So I'm not creating the map like that. Instead I'm placing it (app-map-openlayers) in template in way described in question. My question was more general and only about how to do it for any dynamically created control. Now I updated the question to be more open-layers specific because it seemed to be confusing.

Comment: Nice! Huge thanks for Stackblitz example that makes it easily understandable. Unfortunately at the moment I can't pass the MatMenuTrigger like in the example. I have reference to the actual map object however. I have to think a bit about all this. If I want to do it like this the 3rd party map control can also be changed so that I can do it like in your example.

Comment: If you don't have access to the map creation code, you could use the global namespace to transfer a variable, but that is bad architecture (global namespace)

Comment: I tried to create new angular component that contains a div (id=menuopener) with matMenuTriggerFor AND the mat-menu the div is supposed to open.  I added the new app-popup-menu to the template after the app-map-openlayers. Then I tried to get the element with id=menuopener and appendChild for the element I create in method createMenuOpener. It didn't work. Do you think something like this can be done?

Comment: Not sure I understand, but if you are trying to create an Angular component by using `createElement`/`appendChild` it won't work

Comment: Please have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68701017/is-it-possible-to-set-html-element-in-an-angular-component-as-child-of-dynamical

Answer (score 0):

mat-menu uses id and attribute combo for opening the menu. Kindly refer https://material.angular.io/components/menu/examples for an example.

You can try with that.

Comment: thanks for your answer but it doesn't really help. I know how it's done with html. however i have no idea how to set [matMenuTriggerFor] for the dynamically created control. or is it even possible.

Comment: could you please try with element.setAttributes() or something like that. I am not sure, but have seen an option like that.