# Is it possible to set html element in an Angular component as child of dynamically created component so that it opens mat-menu?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, openlayers

I am trying to achieve situation described in [How to open mat-menu from button click of a dynamically created open layers custom control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68693505/how-to-open-mat-menu-from-button-click-of-a-dynamically-created-open-layers-cusI)

So I want to add mat-menu opener for open-layers custom control that needs to be created dynamically. In original question there's good answer which I can't use because I don't have conrol for the map creation code.

So I have an angular PopUpMenuComponent (app-popup-menu) with HTML:

```
<div id="mat-menu-opener" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"></div>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

In app.component.html I have only the 3rd party map component that I have no control  and the pop-up menu component :

```
<app-map-openlayers></app-map-openlayers>
<app-popup-menu></app-popup-menu>
```

In app.component.ts the custom control that I want to open the mat-menu i try following:

```
  private createMenuButtonElement(): HTMLElement {
    const element = document.createElement('div');
    element.className = `ol-control button menu-opener`;
    const popUpOpener = document.getElementById('mat-menu-opener');
    if (popUpOpener !== null) {
      element.appendChild(popUpOpener);
    }
    return element;
  }
```

So I'm moving the div-element to custom control's child. The move works but the menu is not opened when I click the control. When I check in developer tools Element-tab the div-element looks ok, but the mat-menu does not.

```
<div class="ol-control button popup-menu-button" data-automation-id="mapBtn" title="">
  <div _ngcontent-ng-cli-universal-c213="" aria-haspopup="true" id="mat-menu-opener" class="mat-menu-trigger" ng-reflect-menu="[object Object]"></div>
</div>
```

mat-menu element is found in page but doesn't have the buttons in it:

```
<app-popup-menu _ngcontent-ng-cli-universal-c360=""></app-popup-menu>
```

The question is: Can this be done this way?

Comment: are you sure you can not access to the method "open" or to the "menu" using a template reference variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the `MatMenuTrigger` as a view child and in the `createMenuButtonElement` function use it to toggle, open or close the menu.

```html
<div id="mat-menu-opener" #trig="matMenuTrigger" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"></div>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
<app-map-openlayers></app-map-openlayers>
```

```js
@ViewChild('trig') menuTrigger: MatMenuTrigger;

private createMenuButtonElement(): HTMLElement {
  const element = document.createElement('div');
  element.className = `ol-control button menu-opener`;
  element.addEventListener('click', () => {
    this.menuTrigger.toggleMenu();
  });
  return element;
}
```

Comment: I knew there was a way to do this in a simple manner. I really appreciate your effort in both questions. Thanks a lot!